# How to access Movieclips individually in a for loop as3

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, for-loop

Lets say that `mySaveNewT.data.myNText = 20`, and in a for loop, 20 MovieClips (`tbox`) are populated on the stage.  When a `tbox` instance gets clicked I want to change its visibility to `false`.

1. How do I reference an individual MovieClip that gets clicked, without having to set every MovieClip's visibility to false?  (i.e if `MC[2]` and `MC[10]` get clicked, but the rest aren't)
2. How do I push this into an Array?

Here is my for loop:

```
    for (var i: Number = 0; i < mySaveNewT.data.myNText; ++i) {
            newText = new tbox();
            newText.x = -220;
            newText.y = -513 + i * 69 + 0 * 3.8;
            VWD.addChild(newText);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To push into an array, and add the click listener and change visibility, see code comments:

```
//you need to define an array to store the clips in
var clickedBoxes:Array = [];  //this makes a new empty array, same as doing: = new Array();

for (var i: Number = 0; i < mySaveNewT.data.myNText; ++i) {
        newText = new tbox();
        newText.x = -220;
        newText.y = -513 + i * 69 + 0 * 3.8;
        VWD.addChild(newText);
        newText.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clipClickHandler,false,0,true); //now you add a click listener to this clip
}

function clipClickHandler(e:MouseEvent):void {
    //e.currentTarget will be a reference to the item that was clicked 

    MovieClip(e.currentTarget).visible= false;  //we wrap e.currentTarget in MovieClip so the compiler knows it has a visible property (casting)
    clickedBoxes.push(e.currentTarget);
}
```

---

To loop through your array later:

```
for(var index:int=0;index<clickedBoxes.length;index++){
    clickedBoxes[index].visible = true; //you may have to cast to avoid a compiler error MovieClip(clickedBoxes[index]).visivle = true;
}
```

Comment: Thx for the answer, is there a way i could push that exact MovieClip(e.currentTarget) to the array, because if  10MC are populated by the for loop(), and the second is clicked i need to push that into the array so i can reference it later.... i.e something like newText[2].visible = false???

Comment: So the array should be all the ones that were clicked?

Comment: yea please, i just dont know how to reference each MovieClip individually from a loop... Thx

Comment: looks great, just i get a a name interval error at   for(var i:int=0;i<clickedBoxes.length;i++){
    clickedBoxes[i].visible = true; //                 MovieClip(clickedBoxes[i]).visivle = true;
}

Comment: Error 1151: a conflict with exists with definition i in namespace interval.

Comment: probably just means you have another `var i` somewhere in the same scope (the loop in your question most likely).   Just replace all instances of `i` with something else: `j` or `index` etc - I updated the answer to show.

Comment: thx, it didnt work, but you gave me the final puzzle peices thank you a million... just one more question do you have any idea where i can move             newText.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clipClickHandler,false,0,true);                                                                               other then the for loop() because the listener doesnt fire immediately because newText isnt initiated at the beginning, only after i equals 1???

Comment: Do share (or suggest an edit to my answer) what you did to get it working for future visitors who have a similar question.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by initiated?